# wordpress plugin for get mysql data

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

can I know how to Use search method for this php code

```
   global $wpdb;

   $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE roll_number = value");

   if( !empty($rows) ) {
      $roll_num = $rows->roll_number;
      $full_name = $rows->full_name;
      $percentage = $rows->percentage;
      $result = $rows->result; 
   }



?>
```

i am very confuse,i want to search data in mysql database using search box,i don't know how to use above code for doing search.

Comment: `roll_number = value` Is `value` an actual term? Should be encapsulated in quotes `roll_number = 'value'`

Comment: What kind of data you need to search ?

Comment: There are already many search data plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcs-wp-custom-search/

Comment: i need sir search,when i enter the roll number in the search box want to get full name and percentage.